# causing error and conflicts with modifications

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, template, modifier

How can I troubleshoot issues with Magento 2 customizations and modifications that are causing errors or conflicts so  please s0lve the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here the solution
Troubleshooting issues with customizations and modifications in Magento 2 can be a challenging task, but here are some steps that you can follow to identify and resolve issues:

Check for errors: Review the logs to identify any error messages related to the customization. You can access the logs in Magento 2 by going to System > Tools > Error Reporting or by reviewing the logs in your web server.

Disable customizations: If you suspect that a customization is causing the issue, disable it temporarily to see if the issue persists. You can disable a customization by renaming or moving its module directory or by disabling it in the Magento 2 Admin panel.

Clear cache: Clear the Magento cache, as some customization changes may not take effect until the cache is cleared.

Use default themes: Switch to the default Magento 2 theme to determine if the issue is theme-related. If the issue is resolved, the problem may be with the custom theme.

Check for conflicts: Check for conflicts between customizations or modules by disabling one at a time and checking if the issue is resolved.

Review code changes: Review the code changes you made in the customization to see if there are any syntax or logic errors.

Seek help: If you are still having trouble identifying the issue, seek help from the Magento community or a Magento developer.

Remember to always make a backup of your store before making any modifications or customization changes to prevent any permanent data loss.